# Navigate sheets in an order

Tags: excel, vba

i have sheets names Day1,Day2,Day3,

copy 2 cell value from Day1 and paste it in another workbook Monday,

copy 2 cell value from Day2 and paste it in another workbook Tuesday,

copy 2 cell value from Day3 and paste it in another workbook Wednesday.

I am looking for a VBA code to activate sheet in a order Day1 copy information and paste it, then come back to Day2 copy information and paste it.
Request your help on this pls

Answer (score 0):

To activate a sheet you must use the method Activate:

```
Worksheets("Day1").Activate
```

However, you don't need to activate a sheet to copy content from it, or to paste to it. You can do this copy and paste by referring to the worksheets and using the argument of the Copy method:

```
Worksheets("Day1").Range("origin_range").Copy Worksheets("Monday").Range("target_range")
```